# Is there an option to contact a view in Spring (Thymeleaf) during the view is already loaded?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, web, thymeleaf

i wanna call a javascript function inside of a thymeleaf view during the view is already loaded is this possible or anyone have an idea how to do this? thanks in advance

Comment: how do you want to call it? When html page is loaded, js code can function there on its own as you want. If you want to make a request from the loaded page to the server without reloading the whole page, use ajax for it

Comment: i wanna call the javascript function from java (from spring)

Comment: you can't do this. The page is created on the server-side and then sent to a user and server has no control over it. Technically full-duplex communication channels (like websockets) can be used for your purpose, but i strongly believe it's not what you want or go for. If you describe what you want to do mor, it would be easier to offer another easier solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, The page is created on the server-side and then sent to a user and server has no control over it.